# Tell me, the structure below is okay?

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, pronouns, present-simple, active-voice

> 1. This profile frame is created by me?
> 2. This profile frame has created by me?
> 3. This profile frame has been created by me?
> 4. This profile frame has created by mine?

which one is correct?
give your explanation...

Comment: Welcome to ell Naser. Please provide your opinion about those 4 sentences. What do *you* think about them? If you provide your opinion then people can help you with this question. Otherwise, you will not receive any answer.

Comment: #2 - the *frame* made something next to you or it made something by your agency (it used you to make something). #4 with "was" instead of with "has" - the frame was made by your kids / staff / family / etc. #4 as is - similar to #2, but with reference to your kids etc instead of to you.

Comment: @Cardinal Oops, sorry - having too much fun with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most correct is

> This profile frame **has been created** by me.

since "**created**" is in the past

> This profile frame is created by me.

although understandable, should read

> This profile frame **was created** by me.

Your other two sentences are incorrect

> This profile frame **has created** by me.

sounds like the profile frame "**created**" something

> This profile frame **has created** by **mine**.

the *possessive* "**by mine**" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not " I created the profile frame" ? To me it sounds more direct and to the point.( unless I'm making a mistake )

Comment: Yes, this is the way to convey this with active voice.